# Redirect to Page.aspx redirects to undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, redirect

Simple JavaScript redirect `window.location.href = https://example.org/Page.aspx?q=123` to .aspx resource causes page to navigate to `https://example.org/undefined?q=123`.

Manual navigation to the address works as expected.

I am not familiar with ASP.NET much so I was wondering if that's a common problem or is it only specific to the project that I am working on?

If we assume that some script modifies the URL later down the line, is there any way to stop that?
`e.preventDefault()`? Or `stopImmediatePropagation()`?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Used code snippet:

```
$('body').on('keydown', selectorSearchBoxInput, function (e) {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !!inputValue) {
        var newHref = 'https://example.org/Category/SubCategory/Page.aspx?q=' + encodeURIComponent(inputValue.trim());
        window.location.href = newHref;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, `window.location.href` does not modify the URL in any way, can you show the part of your code where you are assigning it to your given URL?

Comment: @YannickK I've updated the post!

Comment: Hey Andrew, I am confused, this is a different URL you are trying to redirect to. What error are you getting back from this function?

Comment: @YannickK, sorry for confusion, yes the initial URL was shortened to keep it simpler. The error that I'm getting is that when the redirection occurs, browser (Chrome) navigates to `https://example.org/Category/SubCategory/undefined?q=...`.